# How can I prevent normal users from being able to look up other logged-in users?

Tags: systemd, security, d-bus, privacy, logind

For security and privacy reasons, I want to stop logging logins, as well as hiding information about currently logged-in users.

So far, I tried revoking reading permissions to utmp and wtmp:

```
sudo chmod o-r /var/run/utmp
sudo chmod o-r /var/log/wtmp
```

Which successfully stops `w` and `who` commands from working. They return without information about other users.

However, as demonstrated in the answer in ["Other users are logged in" how does the system know? Where is the information leaking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734857/other-users-are-logged-in-how-does-the-system-know-where-is-the-information-l) it is still possible to access the information about other logged-in users via a DBus call to systemd-logind or elogind.

How can I disable this specific DBus call? Or, in general, how can I prevent normal users from being able to look up other logged-in users?

Comment: In general you can not. Unix was designed to be used by a group of people. The best you can do is set up some kind of container environment or virtual machine and give each person their own container or vm.

Comment: For a start you'll have to disable `ps` and `top`. `ls -l /proc` is also a problem. Last update of `/home/user` could also leak information. If you really want to keep every user from knowing about other users the best best is a vm or container specific to each user.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `chroot` environment for your users, then you'll have complete control over the available commands.